# Within "Where" Clause filter the same time period between two different days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To clarify the title:

I've got two columns:

- VisitationDate: The date that someone visited a store. ex.) '2020-01-01'
- VisitationDateTime: A DateTime object. ex.) '2020-01-01 00:00:00'

Within a where clause, I'm trying to select/filter a date range that is between '2020-01-01 00:00:00' to '2020-01-01 12:00:00' and the same exact time frame but on 01/03.

Other way of writing it:

I want the select these date/time ranges:

1. 2020-01-01: Midnight to 12PM
2. 2020-01-03: Midnight to 12PM

Comment: use `BETWEEN` and `OR` -->  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE this_date BETWEEN x AND y OR this_date BETWEEN a AND b`

Comment: `select * from t where my_date between '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2020-01-01 12:00:00'  or my_date between '2020-01-03 00:00:00' and '2020-01-03 12:00:00'`.

Comment: @TheImpaler -- Overachiever!  lol

Comment: seems its to '2020-01-0312:00:00'.. please check

Comment: @TheImpaler `BETWEEN` is usually a bad idea with dates, normally you want a half-open interval, see https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly#hs_cos_wrapper_module_155664132707412123213123455613

Comment: @Charlieface Agreed.

Comment: Your requirement "Midnight to 12PM" can be captured with the predicate `DATEPART(hour, VisitationDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 11`. Combine that with `VisitationDate IN ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03')` and you should be done.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from myTable
where (visitationDateTime >= '20200101' and visitationDateTime < '20200101 12:00') or
(visitationDateTime >= '20200103' and visitationDateTime < '20200103 12:00');
```

Note that using BETWEEN for datetime range checks in MS SQL server is not a good idea. The better way is to use upper boundary exclusive using <.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please select it as answered and give the credit to @Cetin for putting in the time to answer you.

Comment: And do the same for all your previous questions.